# Access Report - Show field1 if field2 equals field3

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have testing/quiz data and I'm trying to do a listing for each test-taker. So I have:

```
QuestionText
    Answer1
    Answer2
    Answer3
    Answer4
```

I also have two fields... one is 'RightWrong' (which has a 1 if they got it right and a 0 if they got it wrong), and the other is 'Response' (which is the answer a test-taker gave that will match Answer1, 2, 3, or 4).

What I want to do is have a field after Answer1 (or highlight Answer1) that goes something like this:

```
IF [RESPONSE]=[ANSWER1] AND [RIGHTWRONG]="1" THEN (somehow show it as correct)
```

After Answer2:

```
IF [RESPONSE]=[ANSWER2] AND [RIGHTWRONG]="1" THEN (somehow show THIS as correct)
```

etc.

Can this be done with Conditional Formatting? If not, what kind of code do I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click the TextBox and choose "Conditional Formatting...". Then enter something like this

[image]

---

If you have only one textbox that is repeated for each record, then the "`[RESPONSE]=[ANSWER1] And`" part is not necessary of cause. Enter only `[RIGHTWRONG]="1"` as expression.

If you want to format a textbox that is bound to the field `RightWrong` you can simplify it further like this

[image]

---

And if the `RightWrong` field is typed as Integer or Long drop the double quotes around `1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally format RESPONSE in a report based on the value of RIGHTWRONG using Conditional Formatting.

You just need to use "Expression Is" instead of "Field Value Is" and put in the formula `[RIGHTWRONG]=1` and optionally a second formula `[RIGHTWRONG]=0` for wrong answers.

**Example**

[image]

**Output**

[image]